# Global variables to submodule

Tags: python, module, global, package

I have a module which consists of function that uses functions imported from another module. Lets call it the main function.

I want to set some variables in the main function as globals and use them in the functions of imported submodules as globals (there's specific thing that I can't use them as arguments of function)
Can't figure out how to do this. My example:

```
#submodule.py
def subfunction():
    print COLORS

#mainmodule.py

from submodule import subfunction

def main(colors, x, y, z):
    global COLORS
    COLORS=colors
    subfunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to create a class `Color` and to use a static variable `values`.

File Color.py:

```
class Colors:
    values = [255, 0, 0]
```

File main.py:

```
from Color import Colors

def main():
    # Default:
    print Colors.values

    # New:
    Colors.values = [0, 255, 0]
    print Colors.values

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
[255, 0, 0]
[0, 255, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. There's something called "coupling" used as a metric of programming complexity. Basically the more loosely things are coupled the better, which means that the values used by a piece of code should be passed explicitly to that code. Therefore you should write your example along these lines:

```
#submodule.py
def subfunction(colors):
    print colors

#mainmodule.py
from submodule import subfunction

def main(colors, x, y, z):
    global COLORS
    colors = COLORS
    subfunction(colors)
```

Even so your use of `global` to set the value for COLORS in `mainmodule` is somewhat dubious, as it tightens the coupling. Presumably its purpose is so that other funcitons in the module can make use of COLORS without having to explicitly pass the value, but that isn't a terribly good idea.

Comment: Python 2 is obsolete. print(colors) is the way to write things now.

Comment: I'm well aware of that thank you. I presume you realise this answer was written in 2016. There are thousands of such answers in Stackoverflow. Would you have the authors go back and revise them all?